# MSSql - Query analyzer, determinate columns type and allow nullable

Tags: sql-server

I have a lot of SQL queries, each of them depends on a few tables(inner, left join...)
I am looking for a quick way to determinate which columns, their type, and allowing nullable for them.
My goal is to create models for C#. I can analyze each query manually(check column type in the table and check if this table is included in a left join). But I hope that it could be automated.

Comment: Does [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) help?

Comment: @Larnu Yes! Thank you, It is what I needed.